# Increased BigQuery errors?

Tags: google-bigquery

We've been seen increased BigQuery errors all day. About every ~10th or so job has been failing with "Errors encountered during job execution. Unexpected. Please try again."

Some of the job ids are:

```
job_9d954736de884aa4a69adc3f10d296f1
job_b1ed9c2953f3460fb9f205080d05e204
job_410130a620674625a7e87f7d8608cdce
job_b38e3b0bd75a4fcea46aa278fddea319
```

Any idea what is going on and if theres a timeline for resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particular tables you're using are tickling a bug in our query execution engine. We've fixed the issue. Let us know if you encounter it again.

Comment: Cool thanks. Are there any plans on your end to put together a status dashboard or a Twitter account that we can monitor to spot issues like this?

Comment: Yes, there are plans to add a public-facing status dashboard. In the mean time, you could fixup your tables by exporting them to json and then re-importing them. I'll update this thread when the new execution engine is released.